# An edit shows a tag was both removed and added

Tags: bug, tags, editing

In [this edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/35078/revisions) of mine last January, it shows that the tag [dns-domain] was both removed and added.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Might be because the tag changed it's position, but I'm also not sure...

Comment: @AleksanderRas Yeah, I was thinking the same. Still a bug I would assume, since it's about added/removed tags and not their positioning.

Comment: Looks like the order of the tag is based on how many questions there are, and [tag:dns-domain] was [*first created* on that question](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/35364/revisions), and now it has 105 questions currently, placing it the 3rd out of 5 tags. The ordering is important though because it affects [the shown title on the search engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S05O.png) if the 1st tag is not mentioned on the title.

Comment: It didn't make it into the first spot so that didn't change. And if we want to log all such ordering changes, shouldn't they all be visible in the post's history? It just seems odd to me, a SE person might want to confirm whether it's intended behaviour or a bug.

Comment: I am thinking perhaps the tag was a rename? IE a different tag was removed, which has since been renamed to dns-domain …

Comment: @AviD That makes sense! There are no unique identifiers visible, also not in the HTML, so I guess we can't really tell for sure, but this does make sense. I'd still think it's a bug that this is shown as edit, but at least one that can be explained :)

Comment: I guess? No idea if its true though... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯